# In Access, how to build the range data picker for query or form?

Tags: ms-access

I want to use form to show the data between two date, can I use range date picker function? how?

Answer (score 0):

You just need two text boxes set to date and then some VBA or a parameter query to query a table.

Check out this page:

http://allenbrowne.com/casu-08.html

Comment: Actually, I always unsuccessfully link the text box to the date